# thread pool not executing in service

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Hi stackoverflow community...

I am a little stumped. I have written an application to control collect printing stats, each print job is managed by a new thread and as a console application the code works a treat. When I try initialize the same thread queue worker in a service, it does not run through the class it is meant to launch. This only happens on Windows 8 works stations.

Here are some code snippets.

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.
        Dim tmp As New pmon_Audit
        objwriter.AutoFlush = True
        tmp.StartAudit()
    End Sub


Imports SpoolMonitor
Imports System.Printing
Imports System.Threading
Imports Amib.Threading
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class pmon_Audit
    Friend WithEvents pmon As New PrinterMonitorComponent
    Public ThreadPool As New SmartThreadPool(10, 1000, 0)

    Public Sub StartAudit()

        pmon.MonitorJobAddedEvent = True
        '' Add printer to monitor 
        Try
            For Each p As PrinterInformation In New PrinterInformationCollection
                Try
                    pmon.AddPrinter(p.PrinterName)
                    WriteLog(String.Format("Printer {0} added to monitor", p.PrinterName))
                Catch ex As Exception
                    WriteLog(ex.ToString)
                End Try
            Next p
        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteLog(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub


''' <summary>
    ''' Event that gets fired  each time a job is added
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>

    Private Sub pmon_jobAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintJobEventArgs) Handles pmon.JobAdded
        Dim myPrintServer As New LocalPrintServer(PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministrateServer)
        Try
            Dim pq As PrintQueue = myPrintServer.GetPrintQueue(e.PrintJob.PrinterName)
            Dim jobAdded As New pmon_JobAdded(e.PrintJob)

            pq.GetJob(e.PrintJob.JobId).Pause()
            WriteLog("JobID " + e.PrintJob.JobId.ToString + " is paused")

            ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(New Amib.Threading.Action(AddressOf jobAdded.run))


        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteLog(ex.ToString)
        End Try


Public Function run()
        Dim myPrintServer As New LocalPrintServer(PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministrateServer)
        Dim pq As PrintQueue = myPrintServer.GetPrintQueue(pjReceived.PrinterName)
        curPT = pq.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket

        If jb Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("printJobRecord", "printJobRecord is null.")
        End If

        Try
            WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " added to monitor")
            jb.JobID = pjReceived.JobId

            While pjReceived.Spooling
                Thread.Sleep(800)
                pjReceived.Update()
            End While

            Try
                If pjReceived.Color = True Then
                    jb.Colour = 2
                Else
                    jb.Colour = 0
                End If
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " Colour = " + jb.Colour.ToString)
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.Colour = 1
            End Try

            Try
                jb.Account = pjReceived.UserName
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " Account = " + jb.Account)
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.Account = "Admin"
            End Try

            Try
                jb.Application = pjReceived.Document
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " Application = " + jb.Application)
            Catch ex As Exception
                WriteLog(ex.ToString)
            End Try

            Try
                If pq.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.CopyCount > pjReceived.Copies Then
                    jb.Copies = pq.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.CopyCount
                ElseIf pq.UserPrintTicket.CopyCount > pjReceived.Copies Then
                    jb.Copies = pq.UserPrintTicket.CopyCount
                Else
                    jb.Copies = pjReceived.Copies
                End If
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " Copies = " + jb.Copies.ToString)
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.Copies = 1
            End Try

            Try
                jb.DeviceName = pjReceived.PrinterName
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " PrinterName = " + jb.DeviceName)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            Try
                jb.DataType = pjReceived.DataType
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            Try
                jb.Document = pjReceived.Document
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " Document = " + jb.Document)
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.Document = "UNKNOWN"
            End Try

            Try
                jb.Driver = pjReceived.DriverName
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " Driver = " + jb.Driver)
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.Driver = "UNKOWN"
            End Try

            Try
                If pq.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.Duplexing > pq.UserPrintTicket.Duplexing Then
                    jb.Duplex = pq.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.Duplexing
                Else
                    jb.Duplex = pq.UserPrintTicket.Duplexing
                End If

                If jb.Duplex = "twoSided" Then
                    jb.Duplex = "1"
                Else
                    jb.Duplex = "0"
                End If

                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " Duplex = " + jb.Duplex)
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.Duplex = "0"
            End Try

            Try
                jb.JobDate = pjReceived.Submitted
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " JobDate = " + jb.JobDate)
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.JobDate = Date.Now
            End Try

            Try
                jb.JobSize = pjReceived.JobSize
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.JobSize = "0"
            End Try

            Try
                jb.Location = Dns.GetHostName.ToUpper
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " Location = " + jb.Location)
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.Location = "UNKOWN"
            End Try

            Try
                jb.Media = pq.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaSize.PageMediaSizeName
                jb.Media = pjReceived.PaperKind
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " Media = " + jb.Media)
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.Media = "201"
            End Try

            Try
                jb.NUP = pq.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PagesPerSheet
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.NUP = 0
            End Try

            Try
                jb.PageCount = pjReceived.TotalPages
                WriteLog("JobID " + pjReceived.JobId.ToString + " PageCount = " + jb.PageCount.ToString)
            Catch ex As Exception
                jb.PageCount = 1
            End Try

            Try
                jb.PortName = pq.QueuePort.Name
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            Try
                myPrintServer.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                WriteLog(ex.ToString)
            End Try

        Catch ex As Exception
            pq.GetJob(pjReceived.JobId).Resume()
            myPrintServer.Dispose()
            WriteLog(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        GC.Collect()
        Return 0
    End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried running the service using the same identity which the program works for as a console application? I'm suspecting a permissions problem.

Comment: Does the service start and then stop, or does it stay running but not work?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Nor did you provide enough information for us to guess what your question might be, beyond "my code doesn't work, can you fix it for me?"

Comment: It turns out it was a permissions issue. One of the DLL's I was using did not have permission to the particular structure it was trying to access. Thank you